# If someone is under the effect of microcosm, does putting the physical body in quintessence affect their dream world?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

Does putting someone's physical body in [quintessence](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/q/quintessence), thus removing them from the time stream, also remove them from the [dream demiplane](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-rules/esoteric-planes/#Dimension_of_Dreams) their mind was sent to by [Microcosm](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/m/microcosm)?

The point of this is to see if we can separate the mind and body and use [Dream Travel](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/d/dream-travel) to go to the dream created by Microcosm, with the body of the dreamer safely stored in Quintessence.

All of this assumes that Microcosm does create a dream demiplane, which by RAW may be dubious. But if it does, cheap pocket plane with better time traits we could otherwise get. Downside: dealing with monsters of the dream world might suck. Upside, pretty hard to get there if you're not a creature related to dreams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing about *microcosm* that suggests that the mind is actually separated from the body—the mind is cut off from the physical world, but “its own little world” seems to be entirely in its head (or in the shared consciousness of those in the area), but it is still in the body. If the body dies—the spell explicitly references starvation as a possibility—the mind dies as well, for all it is unaware of the body’s needs.

In the same way, if the body is removed from time’s flow—such as by being submerged in *quintessence*—then the mind is frozen as well. Whether this appears to others in the shared *microcosm* as though the subject was frozen in their world, or if they just disappear, is unclear, but they definitely cannot continue to act, there or anywhere else.

So no, this does not work.